# UiBinder: Package not found

Tags: gwt, widget, uibinder

I tried to import one of my widgets in another ui.xml file.
In eclipse no errors are shown but in (maven) development mode it says:
`[ERROR] Package not found: de.s.pp.client.application.projectdetail.overview.subview`

The widget that imports:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
    xmlns:ovs='urn:import:de.s.pp.client.application.projectdetail.overview.subview'>

    <ovs:ProjectProperties/>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

ProjectProperties.java:

```
    package de.s.pp.client.application.projectdetail.overview.subview;

import com.google.common.io.Resources;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class ProjectProperties extends Composite {
    interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, ProjectProperties> {
    }

    private static MyUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);
    private Resources resources;

    public ProjectProperties() {
        super();
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    public ProjectProperties(Resources resources) {
        this();
        this.resources = resources;
    }

}
```

ProjectProperties.ui.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <ui:style>

    </ui:style>
    <g:CaptionPanel width="95%" captionText="Projekteigenschaften">

    </g:CaptionPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Comment: Did you forget to inherit any modules??? or did you forget to place both view.java and uibinder file in same package.

Comment: The ProjectProperties.java and .ui.xml are in the same package. The view that uses the widget is in another package. But everything is in the same module.

Comment: if possible try to rename the file to some other name, i mean the widget name.

Comment: thanks for your possible solutions, but I found the answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the absolute path of the file was to long

Comment: Actually I shortened the path. So this is a kind of Workaround

Answer (score 1):

Did you forgot to add jar file, to use the de.s.pp.client.application.projectdetail.overview.subview